# nvidia display setting are not available

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

One day, my laptop suddenly heated up and it suddenly showed 6 screen in single display.

I reboot my system 2-3 times and the problem seems to go away. But 1-2 days later it returned.  I tried rebooting again but this time problem only resolved partially. I mean, It is showing single screen but graphics card not working. It also disabled the sleep and the hibernate option.

When I try to open the nVidia Control Panel I get this error:

[image: Error message]

In the Device Manager the GPU shows up with a yellow exclamation mark and error 43, which is a generic error.

[image: Device manager screenshot]

I'm still confused, what's the exact problem, whether my graphics card gone or if it is a driver issue. Even I tried [this solution](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/510574/geforce-500-400-series/nvidia-display-settings-are-not-available-you-are-not-currently-using-a-display-attached-to-an-nvidi/), but it wasn't helpful.

My current system configuration is :

- OS : Windows 7 Professional
- RAM : 3GB
- Display adapter : Nvidia GeForce 8400M GS (256 MB)

Comment: Did it work before or did the card just stop working? Did you change any drivers or any hardware before the error showed up. (My **current** system configuration seems to hint that you did). Does the card work if you boot another OS (e.g. download a liveCD, boot that and check if the card works. If it does not work then it is not a software failure but probably a hardware failure. Vice versa if it does then the HW is probably OK).

Comment: One day, my laptop suddenly heated up and then it suddenly start showing 6 screen in single display. But, I reboot my system 2-3 times and that problem resolved for 1-2 days. But later, again same problem appears (6 screens), I did same thing, but this time problem resolved partially. I mean, It is showing single screen but graphics card not working. Even, now **Sleep** and **Hibernate** option is disabled. :( and that's more painful for me. :(

Comment: AFAIK, I didn't installed any software before this problem.

Comment: Sleep and hibernate probably ask a lot of drivers to put their devices into sleep mode. If this includes the graphical card and then one has a problem...   Anyway, It starts to sound as if your hardware may indeed have broken. :(

Comment: is there any way to test my hardware except device manager. Because, I tried that option many time and stuck while searching some drivers.

Comment: Try booting another OS. That way you are using different drives.  E.g. use [a liveCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD).

Answer (score 0):

The first problem, due to driver crash when you try to install a new diplay driver.
The second problem is that the diplay driver you installed is incompatible.
The solution is:

1. Open Device Manager.
2. Expand the category “Display adapters”. Right-click on NVIDIA graphics card name and select “Uninstall” on the context menu.
   [image: Device Manager → context menu]
   Your computer will start automatically and you will delete it again.
3. If prompted to confirm the uninstall, check the box next to “Delete the driver software for this device” and click the “OK” button.
   [image: “Confirm Device Uninstall” dialog]
4. Restart your computer.  Windows will reload the driver.